# Extracting first-layer weights from a multi-layer Keras NN and transferring them to a single layer NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a 3-hidden layer NN (3-HL) using Keras (with good results, and I wanted to extract the weights from its first layer (inputs to its first-hidden layer) and use them in a single-hidden layer NN (inputs to its single hidden layer), to train. The 3-HL model summary along with its extracted (hopefully first layer) weight dimensions is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7FKk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cCUL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA8XI.png)

And here are the same info for the single-hidden layer which I aim to train using the extracted first-layer weights from the above model:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Ys6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O9Vn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuDrO.png)

As you can see. both weights seem to have similar shape and size and dimensions. But when I put this line to set the single-hidden layer model weights, I get a valueError as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLLM3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SDyH.png)

Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: Are you getting just weights or both w and biases as well ?

Comment: Doing this: transfered_model_weights = transfered_model.layers[0].get_weights()[0] is supposed to only give me weights. My understanding is that by doing this instead, transfered_model_weights = transfered_model.layers[0].get_weights()[1] it would give me biases. But the problem is how to fix it so it can extract weights and/ weights&biases and use them into the new model

Comment: Please _do not post pictures of code_; having to click on eight separate images to get an idea of what you are doing is awful. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also make a _complete_ example; for example you are not even showing how you define `transfer_model_weights`.

Comment: My apologies. I see how it is difficult.  transfered_model_weights = transfered_model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting weights and the biases separately you should get them together and input that into `set_weights()` function. Try following:

```py
model.layers[0].set_weights(transfered_model.layers[0].get_weights())
```